# IndexError Exception in Python

Tags: python, exception

Below, we have provided a list of tuples that consist of student names, final exam scores, and whether or not they will pass the class. For some students, the tuple does not have a third element because it is unknown whether or not they will pass. Currently, the for loop does not work. Add a try/except clause so the code runs without an error - if there is no third element in the tuple, no changes should be made to the dictionary.

```
students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'), ('Stewart', 50, 
          'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'), ('Archie', 71), ('Carl', 
           45, 'Will not pass')]

passing = {'Will pass': 0, 'Will not pass': 0}

for tup in students:
 if tup[2] == 'Will pass':
     passing['Will pass'] += 1
 elif tup[2] == 'Will not pass':
     passing['Will not pass'] += 1
```

If above code is run, it gives error: IndexError: tuple index out of range on line 8
After try/except, it should give {‘Will pass’: 3, ‘Will not pass’:2}

My attempt is:

```
try:
    for tup in students:
       if tup[2] == 'Will pass':
           passing['Will pass'] += 1
       elif tup[2] == 'Will not pass':
           passing['Will not pass'] += 1
except Exception, e:
    print("Continue")
```

it gives {‘Will pass’: 1, ‘Will not pass’:0}

Can someone please advise what is wrong with my try/except? I tried adding two try/except, and still, I got the same output.

Comment: `print("Continue")` does not continue loop; it prints `"Continue"`.

Comment: You might want to bring the `try`-`except` inside the loop and use `continue`.

Comment: ...and also catch IndexError rather than Exception since you know that's the error you're goig to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly check with those tuples where their length is 3. Try this :

```
for tup in students:
    if len(tup)==3:
        if tup[2] == 'Will pass':
            passing['Will pass'] += 1
        elif tup[2] == 'Will not pass':
            passing['Will not pass'] += 1
```

If you insist on using `try-except` block, try this :

```
for tup in students:
    try:
        if tup[2]=='Will pass':
            passing['Will pass'] += 1
        elif tup[2]=='Will not pass':
            passing['Will not pass'] += 1
    except:
        pass
```

**Output**:

```
passing = {'Will pass': 3, 'Will not pass': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your code more robust by checking the tuple length:
The message in the tuple length check assumes you use python 3.5+, you can use `print("Don't know yet if {name} will pass".format(name=tup[0])`

```
students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'), ('Stewart', 50, 
          'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'), ('Archie', 71), ('Carl', 
           45, 'Will not pass')]

passing = {'Will pass': 0, 'Will not pass': 0}

for tup in students:
 if len(tuple) == 2:
   print(f"Don't know yet if {tup[0]} will pass")
   continue
 if tup[2] == 'Will pass':
     passing['Will pass'] += 1
 elif tup[2] == 'Will not pass':
     passing['Will not pass'] += 1
```

Comment: That `continue` can be avoided if you use second `if` as `elif`.

Comment: I used two try/except in the loop and got {‘Will pass’: 2, ‘Will not pass’:1}, Still working on the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the right solution

```
students = [('Timmy', 95, 'Will pass'), ('Martha', 70), ('Betty', 82, 'Will pass'), ('Stewart', 50, 'Will not pass'), ('Ashley', 68), ('Natalie', 99, 'Will pass'), ('Archie', 71), ('Carl', 45, 'Will not pass')]

passing = {'Will pass': 0, 'Will not pass': 0}

for tup in students:
    try:
        if tup[2] == 'Will pass':
            passing['Will pass'] += 1
        elif tup[2] == 'Will not pass':
            passing['Will not pass'] += 1
    except IndexError:
        continue
```